# qhelpgenerator with doxygen keep showing sh : 1 permission denied

Tags: qt, permissions, documentation, doxygen

I want to use doxygen to generate a qt supported .qch file.

I set up all parameters like GENERATE_QHP, QCH_FILE ,QHP_NAMESPACE in .cfg file, also, I set

```
QHG_LOCATION           =  "/home/marty/Qt5.14.0/5.14.0/gcc_64/bin/"
```

When I called doxygen project.cfg, the .html document was successfully created. But when it came to qhelpgenerator, it showed:

```
Running qhelpgenerator...
sh: 1: /home/marty/Qt5.14.0/5.14.0/gcc_64/bin/: Permission denied
error: failed to run qhelpgenerator on index.qhp
lookup cache used 2501/65536 hits=17469 misses=3200
finished...
```

I tried chmod 777 qhelpgenerator, index.qhp and the relevant files that I can think of, and ran

```
sudo doxygen project.cfg
```

the problem still existed. It has already bothered me a whole day.

Any ideas what might happen?

Comment: Which version of doxygen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `QHG_LOCATION` reads:

> The QHG_LOCATION tag can be used to specify the location of Qt's qhelpgenerator. If nonempty doxygen will try to run qhelpgenerator on the generated .qhp file.

I think that the word `QHG_LOCATION` together with the description is a bit misleading here, it should include the name of the executable (analogous to e.g. `HHC_LOCATION`).

(Note: when starting external you can use `doxygen -d extcmd` to see which external commands are attempted to be started).